# Android : How to set TextView text size dynamically so that text do not wrap to next line

Tags: android

I have this piece of code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/textLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/vdaybg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:text="hello"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am setting text dynamically from Activity

```
detailText.setText(msg);
detailText.setTypeface(Utils.typeFaceBold);
```

Now Since I am setting multi line text, bigger lines wrap to next line.
I want to prevent that.
I want to reduce font size when line is about to warp.

currently I have found this piece of code to do that

```
public void correctWidth(TextView textView, int desiredWidth) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();

        paint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
        float textSize = textView.getTextSize();
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

        while (bounds.width() > desiredWidth)
        {
            textSize--;
            paint.setTextSize(textSize);
            paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        }

        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    }
```

But what to pass in desiredWidth? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autosizing TextViews with defining multiple text sizes.

```
<resources>
  <array name="autosize_text_sizes">
    <item>10sp</item>
    <item>12sp</item>
    <item>20sp</item>
    <item>40sp</item>
    <item>100sp</item>
  </array>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes" />
```

This is [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) official documentation from Android Developers website.

Comment: Have tried this but this doesn't prevent line wrap. It will fit to height